# Why there is a dummy node when I am printing a singly linked list?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

My code prints an extra node(garbage value) why?
Is there is any issue with my code?
just let me how to fix it.

```
void push(node **head_ref,int value)  //function to insert a new node on front of the list
{
    node *new_node=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data=value;
    new_node->next=*head_ref;
    *head_ref=new_node;
}

void printll(node *head)    //function to print the list
{
    node *temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Actual Output : 
   45 88 24 34 77 0

Expected Output : 
   45 88 24 34 77

---

Full code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cassert>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void push(node **head_ref,int value)
{
    node *new_node=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data=value;
    new_node->next=*head_ref;
    *head_ref=new_node;
}

void printll(node *head)
{
    node *temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }

}

int main()
{
    node *head= (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    push(&head,77);
    push(&head,34);
    push(&head,24);
    push(&head,88);
    push(&head,45);
    printll(head);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us how you use these functions, and how you initialize the list.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that the last node isn't actually properly initialized to NULL.

Comment: this is the code I have written http://ideone.com/9S1qv6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this definition

```
node *head= (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

you should write simply

```
node *head = NULL;
```

or

```
node *head = nullptr; // C++
```

Otherwise your program has undefined behaviour because the allocated node for the head was not initialized.

Also if it is a C++ program you should use operator `new` instead of C function `malloc`. For example function `push` will look like

```
void push( node * &head_ref, int value )
{
    head_ref = new node { value, head_ref };
}
```

and called like

```
push( head, 77 );
```

Take into account that you have also to write a function that will free the all allocated memory for the list.

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate memory using `malloc` the memory is not initialized in any way, it's content is *indeterminate*. That means that when you allocate the first node (which is a dummy extra node that's not needed) it's `next` pointer is not null, and dereferencing this indeterminate pointer leads to *undefined behavior*.

The simplest solution? Considering your code is closer to C than C++, don't allocate memory initially at all, instead just create a pointer *and initialize it to `NULL`*:

```
node *head = NULL;
```

---

*One* proper way to do it in C++ is to not use `malloc` at all, instead use the C++ operator `new` and add a *constructor* to the `node` structure which initializes it:

```
struct node
{
    node() : data(0), next(nullptr) {}
    node(int d, node* n) : data(d), next(n) {}

    int data;
    node* next;
};

void push(node** head_ref, int value)
{
    *head_ref = new node(value, *head_ref);
}

...

int main()
{
    node* head = nullptr;
    ...
}
```

Now you can create a new node and it will have an initial `value` of `0`, and its `next` pointer will be a null-pointer. You can also, as shown above, create and initialize a new node with specific `value` and `next`.

<sub>[Substitute `nullptr` for `0` if your compiler doesn't support the C++11 `nullptr` value]</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You have a dummy node (head itself) in your design.  So the print function needs to skip that dummy node.